# Transferring Data from within an array in component A to component B to be modified and saved in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am trying to send data that's within a calendar (set up as an array on a calendar.component.ts in angular) to a timesheet.component.ts where an employee can modify their entrance / exit, add or modify notes. On calendar.component.ts the calendar is arranged as an array of objects "arr" that have the date (arr.date), the AM entrance of the employee (arr.entranceAM) etc. Upon clicking on the day of the month the data is displayed and a "Modify" button appears. upon clicking it I go to a timesheet.component.ts where the employee can edit that data (the entrance and exit and the notes, the arr.date would change only based on which day of the month is selected.
I wanted to send this data (arr.data, arr.entranceAM ecc.) to the timesheet.component.ts

```js
modifyButton = "Modify Data";
infoDate = "The Date is: "+ arr.date;
infoAM = "Entrance (AM):" + arr.entranceAM + " - Exit (AM):" arr.exitAM;
infoPM = "Entrance (PM):" + arr.entrancePM + " - Exit (PM):" arr.exitPM;
infoNotes = "Notes: " + arr.note;
```

Below method for clicking on any day of the calendar and displaying the details, including the button to modify entrance and exit and notes on timesheet.component.ts, a separate component that has sliders and such to save the workday hours.

```js
document.getElementById("c_" + (counter + 1)).addEventListener("click", function () {
       
        document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = infoData;
        document.getElementById("am").innerHTML = infoAm;
        document.getElementById("pm").innerHTML = infoPm;
        document.getElementById("note").innerHTML = infoNote;
        document.getElementById("totalHrs").innerHTML = infoOreTot;
        document.getElementById("modif").innerHTML = modifyButton;
```

The button at the bottom has a simple router function that takes to the timesheet component, but so far it only travels to today's date, whereas I want to populate it with arr.date, arr.entranceAm etc.

How can I go about this? My idea so far was something similar:

```js
document.getElementById("modif").onclick = function(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('timesheet').then(function(){
        document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = arr.date;
        document.getElementById("entranceAm").innerHTML = arr.entranceAM;
```

I would substitute the element with id "date" at the timesheet destination with the current date, then do the same with element with id "entranceAM" and so on and so forth. This doesn't seem to work but I can't understand why.

Any help would be appreciated! THank you

Comment: Just an FYI, you really should avoid accessing and manipulating the DOM directly when using Angular.  It won't know about the changes you are making.  It really seems that you need some more knowledge about Angular fundamentals like event binding, routing, components, etc.

Comment: I defenitly do. Where in that do I access the DOM?

Comment: Have you done Agnular's Tour of Heroes tutorial yet?  Its a pretty good way to get started, and it covers probably all of what you are trying to do here. https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the array as `@Input` to component B and then modify it.

Code example:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-a-component'
    template: "<app-b-component [array]='arr'"></app-b-component>"
})
export class AComponent {
   public arr: any[] = [1,2,3];
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-b-component'
    template: "<div *ngFor='item user of _array'>{{item}}</div>"
})
export class BComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() array(arr :any[]) {
      this._array = arr;
      this.arrLength = arr && arr.length;
   };

    public _array: any[];
    public length: number;

}
```

Comment: I can't just pass the array, I need to pass the position that has been clicked.

Comment: then pass also the position, why that wouldn't work?

Comment: Sorry I literally don't know how to do it! I literally started programming 2 weeks ago xD I vaguely know how th e input decorator works but I don't know how to apply it in this case! If you could provide an example I'd greatly appreciate

Comment: If it's good you can also mark this answer as useful by giving it upper vote :) Happy coding